# cshtml file could not be found although it is under Shared folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `cshtml` under *Shared* folder. I am doing a `RedirectToAction()` to this page but its not looking for this file in *Shared* folder. Its only looking in the appropriate folder under views.  It uses to look into *Shared* folder before and I have no idea what I could have changed that breaking lookup. Any ideas?

Comment: If it can't find a view, it must throw exceptions on the lines of ".cshtml file is not found". Can you please post your exception, view model and tell us the name of your shared view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do a `RedirectToAction` to a view. You are doing (as it name suggests) a redirect to an action. It is this action that returns a view. By default it will look for views in the `~/Views/ControllerName` and `~/Views/Shared`. So let's suppose that you have the following action which performs a redirect:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
    }
}
```

which would redirect to the `Index` action on the `Products` controller:

```
public class ProductsController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now the Index.cshtml view could be in `~/Views/Products/Index.cshtml` or in `~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml`.